# How to align Google Adsense AUTO ADS in center?

Tags: ads, adsense, auto, adsense-anchor-ads

I am using blogspot platform and have used Google Adsense on my website. I want to align an auto adsense ads whichis, its not center at all while the ads with code no problem at all. It just auto ads, can someone please help me on this? I believe that it has a trick as well css code somewhere but I am not sure how. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Google auto placed ads has a class **google-auto-placed**.
Adding the following CSS should work.

```
.google-auto-placed {text-align:center;}
```